# SEVERE: A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException in Tomcat?

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I tried lot of things cleaning the tomcat, re-installing eclipse, removing project and the re-adding it, doing mvn clean install after every change still I am getting this. Please anyone with a answer let me know. Even tried Deployment Assembly -> java build path Entries -> maven dependencies -> add maven dependencies.

web.xml :-

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">



    <context:component-scan base-package="ani.main"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SpringMVC</groupId>
  <artifactId>mvcdemp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>mvcdemp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>mvcdemp</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: For starters stop mixing 3 versions of Spring (3.0.4, 3.1.2 and 5.0.1) and rename your `spring.xml` to `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

Comment: thanks i figured it out just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pom.xml spring-web is of lower version increase it to 5.0.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

If you have given teh dispatcher servlet name as dispatcher, it will try looking for a dispatcher-servlet.xml file. It seems you have given spring.xml

Comment: i just changed name from dispatcher to spring but still it didn't work

Comment: it should be spring-servlet.xml - note the"-servlet.xml' suffix

Comment: thanks for your effort most appreciated it's was due to change in versioning of spring-web and spring-context